# Show drive letters next to folder name for explorer windows, on the start bar

Tags: windows

Is there a way to show the drive letters before the folder name  for folders open in an explorer window?
[image]

I usually have many explorer windows open at a time and it would be easier if I could see the drive letter rather than clicking on the navigation bar and pressing the home button to see which drive I am in at the moment.